# Происхождение выражения "черта с два"

Tags: этимология, лексика, фразеология, выбор-слов, история

Иногда в речи можно встретить выражение *черта с два* (ошибочно записываемое как *чертос два*), значащее "не дождетесь", "ни за что". Но откуда оно взялось? Причем здесь *черт* и числительное *два*?

Answer (score 2):

О недостаточно определенных, оцениваемых приблизительно, промежутках времени иногда говорят пользуясь конструкцией «предлог с + числительное»: «часа (/ дня / месяца / года) с два». То же, о расстоянии - «версты с две» или о количестве - «раза (десятка) с два», «с три короба».

«И того у нас разговору было часа с два, и, стоя за рекою, в том разговоре почали чинить промысел и переправу у нас заставили многолюдством своим. [И. А. Желябужский. Дневные записки (1682-1709)]»

Выражения категорического отрицания «ни черта», «черта лысого» употребляются давно и часто:

«… Черта лысого получишь! хотел было, даром хотел отдать, но теперь вот не получишь же! [Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души (1842)]»

«Или опять и зеленая; вот и глядите, ни черта на ней не выходит. [Н. С. Лесков. Некуда (1864)]»

Стоит заменить в исходной конструкции время, расстояние, количество этими «чертями», – получим «черта с два». Если это так и было, то смысл  полученного выражения (кроме отрицания) должен был приобрести оттенок приблизительности, неопределенности. И действительно:

«― Как тут найдешь, черта с два найдешь; слышь, денег нету… напрасно набегается… [Д. В. Григорович. Антон-горемыка (1847)]»

«…поди займи в этом подлом обществе! Дадут черта с два! Дожидайся! [В. В. Крестовский. Панургово стадо (Ч. 1-2) (1869)]»

Иногда (в устоявшемся уже выражении) число чертей прибывало:

«усилили в Аксакове желание быть более на виду своего начальства»! Как, черта с три! Отрекаюсь от князя и всех, кто мог это про меня подумать! [И. С. Аксаков. Письма Ф. А. Бюлеру (1845)]

К настоящему времени оттенок неопределенности этим выражением утрачен. Теперь в «черта с два» осталось только значение категорического отрицания или крайнего несогласия с чем-либо: «ничего подобного», «как бы не так», «ни за что» - о цене, «никогда» - о времени.

Answer (score 1):

**Вот некоторые объяснения:**

http://info-4all.ru/obrazovanie/otkuda-poshlo-virazhenie-quotchyorta-s-dvaquot

Четные и нечетные числа обычно мы встречаем при выборе цветов, четное число ― на похороны, нечетное ― на праздник. Число два выбрано неспроста.  Два ― первое четное число, мистическое, имеющее отношение к нечистой силе. Можно предположить, что второго черта добавляют для усиления негативного значения.

По суеверным народным представлениям черти могут множиться, раздваиваясь. Вот поэтому в этом устойчивом выражении употребляется число ***два*** ― число двоичности, которое считают бесовским, нечистым.

**О числе два**

https://otvet.mail.ru/question/37500448

Два одинаковых предмета, двойные или сдвоенные предметы могли принести несчастье.

Запрещалось двум лицам одновременно совершать одно и то же действие: пить воду, вставать из-за стола, разжигать огонь, вытирать руки одним полотенцем.

Верили, что чёрта можно сразить только одним ударом: если же ударить дважды, он оживет и даже удвоится (мотив чёрта с два ).